# Fill area of x^2+y^2>1 and x^2+y^2>4 using patterns and tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

I am trying to achieve the following picture using `tikzpicture` environment:

[image: What I want]

The inner circle is `x^2+y^2=1` and the other is `x^2+y^2=4`.

What I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                axis on top,
                axis lines = center,
                axis equal image,
                xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
                yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
                xlabel ={$\Re(z)$},
                xtick={1,2},
                ytick={1,2},
                ylabel ={$\Im(z)$},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend style={cells={align=left}},
                legend cell align={left},
                clip=false
            ]
            \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted] ({cos((x) r)},{sin((x) r)});
            \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted] ({2*cos((x) r)},{2*sin((x) r)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have tried]

I want to add pattern lines for `x^2+y^2>1` and `x^2+y^2>4`, but I do not know how to do it.

As a help you can rely on this example that I made a while ago:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, patterns}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \pgfplotsset{ticks=none}
            \begin{axis}[
                axis equal image,
            axis lines = center,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
                xmax=3,
                xmin=-3,
                legend pos=outer north east,
                axis background/.style={%
          preaction={
           path picture={
                        \draw[pattern=north west lines, pattern color=red,draw=white] (axis cs:1,-3) rectangle (axis cs:3,3);
                        \draw[pattern=north east lines, pattern color=blue,draw=white] (axis cs:1,3) rectangle (axis cs:-3,-3);
           }}},
                xtick={1,2}
                ]
                \node at (axis cs: 2,2.6) {$x^2+y$};
                \node at (axis cs: -2,2.6) {$3x-y$};
                \addplot[very thick, red] coordinates {(1,-3) (1,3)};
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the main "algorithm" for the figure. I am pretty sure you know how to do the rest :)

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={fill=white,inner sep=1pt},node distance=.3em,
    >=stealth]
\path[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (2);
\path[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (-2.5,-2.5) rectangle (2.5,2.5);
\filldraw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (1);
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\path (0,0) node[below left] {$O$}
    (1,0) node[below right] {$1$}
    (2,0) node[below right] {$2$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to use `pgfplots`, everything is similar.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        axis on top,
        axis lines = center,
        axis equal image,
        xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize}, % I can't read \tiny fonts :)
        yticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize}, 
        xlabel ={$\Re(z)$},
        xtick={1,2},
        ytick={1,2},
        ylabel ={$\Im(z)$},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left},
        clip=false
    ]
    \path[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] 
        (axis cs: -2,-2) rectangle (axis cs: 2,2);
    \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted,fill=white] 
        ({2*cos((x) r)},{2*sin((x) r)});
    \path[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] 
        (axis cs: -2,-2) rectangle (axis cs: 2,2);
    \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted,fill=white] 
        ({cos((x) r)},{sin((x) r)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Sorry for bad rendered images – `latexmkrc` can't do anything better I think, and the temporary viewer I am working with does not work well with `patterns`)

---

With *manual* legend entries (hmm, we can't add automatically, because we are not plotting them with `\addplot`, but with tricks. Also, I can't find a better position for the legend XD

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        axis on top,
        axis lines = center,
        axis equal image,
        xticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize}, % I can't read \tiny fonts :)
        yticklabel style = {font=\footnotesize}, 
        xlabel ={$\Re(z)$},
        xtick={1,2},
        ytick={1,2},
        ylabel ={$\Im(z)$},
        legend pos=outer north east,
        legend style={cells={align=left}},
        legend cell align={left},
        clip=false
    ]
    \path[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] 
        (axis cs: -2,-2) rectangle (axis cs: 2,2);
    \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted,fill=white] 
        ({2*cos((x) r)},{2*sin((x) r)});
    \path[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] 
        (axis cs: -2,-2) rectangle (axis cs: 2,2);
    \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted,fill=white] 
        ({cos((x) r)},{sin((x) r)});
    \matrix[draw,fill=white,ampersand replacement=\&,matrix of math nodes,
            nodes={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=2pt},below right]
    at (axis cs: 2,2) {%
        \path[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (-4pt,0pt) rectangle (4pt,8pt); \&
        x^2+y^2>1\\
        \path[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue] (-4pt,0pt) rectangle (4pt,8pt); \&
        x^2+y^2>4\\
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thank you!! It would be possible to draw the same but using the `pgfplots` axis like my first code block?

Comment: @manooooh Legend entry added.

Answer (score 7):

For completeness: with `even odd rule` instead of filling with white.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue,even odd rule] (-2.5,-2.5)
rectangle (2.5,2.5) (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\path[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red,even odd rule] (-2.5,-2.5)
rectangle (2.5,2.5) (0,0) circle[radius=1cm];
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1cm] (0,0) circle[radius=2cm];
\draw[-latex] (-3,0) -- (3,0);
\draw[-latex] (0,-3) -- (0,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or pgfplots.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in,footskip=0.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis} [
                axis on top,
                axis lines = center,
                axis equal image,
                xticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
                yticklabel style = {font=\tiny},
                xlabel ={$\Re(z)$},
                xtick={1,2},
                ytick={1,2},
                ylabel ={$\Im(z)$},
                legend pos=outer north east,
                legend style={cells={align=left}},
                legend cell align={left},
                clip=false,enlargelimits=0.1
            ]
            \path[pattern=north west lines,pattern color=blue,even odd rule] 
               (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east) 
               (0,0) circle(2);
            \path[pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red,even odd rule] 
                (current axis.south west) rectangle (current axis.north east) 
                 (0,0) circle(1);
            \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted] ({cos((x) r)},{sin((x) r)});
            \addplot[very thick,red,smooth,domain=0:2*pi,dotted] ({2*cos((x) r)},{2*sin((x) r)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My compliments to you and JouleV for your answer and for the question. Very nice the patterns.

Comment: Thanks! It would be possible to have a coordinate of system axis i.e. replicating `\begin{axis}` as my first picture?

Comment: @manooooh Do you want to add this to a `pgfplots` axis or use "plain" Ti*k*Z?

Comment: The same syntax as my first source code. I want to add this to a `pgfplits` axis.

Comment: @manooooh Done/

Comment: I did not know how to use `\path` and your secret was to use `circle(...)`, awesome!!

Comment: Is it possible to add the legend entries as my first image posted using your second solution?